# Get values from irregular nested list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, nested

I have a nested list (list of list of dict) where the second list is irregular. I want to get all values of a certain key in an array.

List for each row:

```
[{'0.1':1},{'0.2':2},{'0.3':3}]

[{'0.2':2},{'0.3':3},{'0.4':4},{'0.5':5}]

[{'0.1':1},{'0.2':2}]

[{'0.5':5}]
```

I want all values for the '0.5' key stored into an array. I tried multiple versions of:

```
[record[i]['0.5'] for i in record]

-->TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

    for d in record.values():
        print(d['0.5'])

-->AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Comment: Do NOT use `list` as a variable name.

Comment: Why you edit question body and change variable name here , do that in code!

Comment: Do you just want to print those values? Or do you want to put them into a list? If you want a list, do you just want a flat list? Or do you want a list of lists corresponding to the original list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
s = [[{'0.1':1},{'0.2':2},{'0.3':3}], [{'0.2':2},{'0.3':3},{'0.4':4},{'0.5':5}], [{'0.1':1},{'0.2':2}], [{'0.5':5}]]
new_vals = [c[0] for c in [[b["0.5"] for b in i if "0.5" in b] for i in s] if c]
```

Output:

```
[5, 5]
```

Comment: Ok perfect, this worked. So if i understand this correct then s is the complete list, c the list of list and b contains each key and value of the dict.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this is with a double loop in a list comprehension:

```
record = [
    [{'0.1': 1}, {'0.2': 2}, {'0.3': 3}],
    [{'0.2': 2}, {'0.3': 3}, {'0.4': 4}, {'0.5': 5}],
    [{'0.1': 1}, {'0.2': 2}],
    [{'0.5': 5}],
]

output = [d['0.5'] for row in record for d in row if '0.5' in d]
print(output)
```

**output**

```
[5, 5]
```